# Giftteaser extension not working in admin panel when editing an order [Opencart]

Tags: opencart

When I edit an order from the admin panel, giftteaser won't work. Even the already gifted products start to add up in totals with their actual price. which in think means, Giftteaser don't work with API cart. or am I getting something wrong? any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add some more information to your question. Is there any error message?

Comment: You can ask suggestions for Extension Owners. They give a better and faster solution.